# Jquery ajax returning null values back to controller - MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I'm using jQuery ajax to build a viewmodel list and then trying to send that viewmodel to another ActionResult in order to create PartialViews.  The first part works well, and I'm able to create the viewmodel (List), but when I try to send the viewmodel back to the controller to build up the partial views, everything within the viewmodel is 0.  It returns the correct number of items in the list, but it seems to lose the values.

Can anyone see if I'm missing anything here?

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    url: '@Url.Action("GetMapDetails")',
    success: function (data) {
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetMapItems")',
            data: {
                list: data
            },
            success: function (list) {
                //callback
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and the controller:

```
public ActionResult GetMapDetails()
{
    List<ViewModel> vm = new List<ViewModel>();

    //create viewmodel here 

    return Json(vm.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetMapItems(List<ViewModel> list)
{
    return PartialView("_MapItemsPartial", list);
}
```

I've tried also using `contentType: 'application/json'` and `JSON.stringify(data)` but that gave me an `Invalid JSON primitive` error.

Any help appreciated - thanks

Comment: Try returning a JsonResult when you return Json data

Comment: Remove the `dataType: "json"` because `GetMapItems` return html not JSON

Comment: Also don't serve GET Json requests unless you have validated that the request is an AJAX request, or you are vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the tips folks - I've amended my code to suit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could send them as JSON request:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '@Url.Action("GetMapItems")',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        list: data
    }),
    success: function (result) {
        //callback
    }
});
```

Also notice that I have removed the `dataType: 'json'` parameter because your `GetMapItems` POST controller action doesn't return any JSON. It returns a `PartialView`. So I guess you did something wrong and this is not what it was meant to be returned from this controller action because from what I can see in your success callback you are expecting to manipulate JSON.

Oh, and please remove this `async:false` => it defeats the whole purpose of AJAX as you are no longer doing any AJAX, you are now doing SJAX.

Comment: Hi Darin, that works perfectly thanks.  Was sure I'd already tried that variation, but obviously not! Working great now